# Parse Linux df output with C# regular expressions

Tags: c#, .net, regex, shell

How do I parse the df-Bk Linux command output with C# regular expressions?

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             7913216K  2348412K  5165992K  32% /
varrun                 257788K      108K   257680K   1% /var/run
varlock                257788K        0K   257788K   0% /var/lock
udev                   257788K       56K   257732K   1% /dev
```

I wish to get "1K-blocks" and "Used".

Comment: I think you should provide more to get help.

Comment: Example output would go a long way to helping here.

Comment: Can you show the example of command and describe what exactly you need to parse?

Comment: have you considered piping the output of `df` through `awk` first? (http://www.linuxfocus.org/English/September1999/article103.html)

Comment: How does your regex so far look like? Do you speak regex at all, or are you looking for code monkeys?

Answer (score 5):

Regex is not a magic parsing bullet. Rather than try to parse with regex, why not get the output you want more directly and just read it?

```
df -Bk| awk '{print $2, $3}'
```

This will get you a set of lines with space-delimited fields. Parsing this becomes a matter of calling string.Split()

```
string[] output_lines; // presumably holds the output of df
for (int i = 0; i < output_lines.Length; i++)
{
    if (i == 0)
        continue;

    string[] b_u = output_lines[i].Split(" ");
    string blocks = b_u[0];
    string used = b_u[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `^\S+\s+(\S+)` or split on `\s+`, skip first line tho.